# Can't texture paint a specific texture; it appears as a mask over all other textures (2.79)

Tags: texture-painting

This is a very weird question, I'm aware :)

I have several meshes, each with its own material, each material with its own texture. This is for a game mod, so they're all simple diffuse textures. I used texture painting to mark the different parts of my texture on some objects. At some point, texture painting stopped working* on a particular object (let's call it object X).

*stopped working = I can paint the texture in the UV editor (Paint mode), but I can't paint the model in the 3D view.

After a bit of frustrated trial and error, I tried texture painting a different object, and... it turns out that on any other object the image of object X's texture appears as a "mask"! What I mean is that, if object Y has a green texture and I paint it with a large red "draw" brush, object Y's texture becomes red where object X's texture is not white, but remains untouched where X's texture is white.

I'm pretty new to texture painting, so I probably did something wrong without noticing. It looks like somehow X's texture has become a sort of "global" mask, but I can't find anything like that anywhere.

I also thought that it may be caused by X's texture having a non-completely-white alpha channel, but after filling it nothing changed. The mask effect seems to be based on the white pixels in that texture. Also, the issue was there also before I edited the image with GIMP, and back then it had no alpha channel.

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal file that shows the bug:

[image]

There are two objects, one of which cannot be painted (but its texture can be edited with the "mask" tool), the other one can be painted but the texture of the first object is applied as a mask.

I also noticed that, if I paint on the second object with the "mask" tool, then the first object's texture is modified.

Comment: could you share a part of your mesh (with the images packed within)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you @moonboots, I uploaded a stripped-down version of my file. You can see the issue with just two objects.

Comment: I can't fix the problem, but if I create a new material, use nodes, create an image texture and paint, it works... I'll continue tomorrow but maybe someone will find ;)

Comment: I can't use nodes though: this is a mod for a game, so I have to use materials with textures (I'm not 100% sure node materials wouldn't work, though).

Comment: in the N panel > Tool > Masking, you've enabled Stencil Mask option, it doesn't fix the problem but not sure it's an option you want to enable

Comment: @moonboots It actually fixes the problem! But... I'm sure I had tried to remove that already, and I was getting an error like "no stencil available"... Well, that fixed the issue, thank you!

Comment: I just noticed I couldn't remove the setting if I was using the mask tool. If I switch to the texdraw tool, I can remove the stencil image.

Comment: after deactivating the mask option I still can't paint though, are you working with 2.8 or 2.7?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that, I'm using 2.79

Comment: oh ok so you were probably in Blender Render mode, which could explain  ;)  so does it work now?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N* panel > *Tool > Masking*, you've enabled *Stencil Mask* option, disable it.

Comment: Note: to be able to remove that setting, I had to switch to the TexDraw tool (or probably any tool other then Mask), otherwise I would get an error.